# jQuery execute function on load()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a form that is updating himself when user change something and recalculate all the values, but some values are taken from php session, so It must to update on page load and calculate the correct value as when onchange().

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.qty').change(function() {
        update_amounts();
    });

    update_amounts(); //<--- must to be executed on document.ready()
});

function update_amounts() {
    var sum = 0.0;
    $('#myTable > tbody  > tr').each(function() {

        var qty = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        var price = $(this).find('.price').val();
        var amount = (qty*price)
        sum+=amount;
        $(this).find('.amount').text(''+amount);
    });
    //calculate the total to sum  
    $('.total').val(sum);
    //calculate total + shipping and add VAT
    var shipping = $('.shipping').val();
    var total = $('.total').val();
    var vat = $('.vat').val();
    //calculate vat
     var vat_value = ((total*vat)/100);
    //calculate grand total

    sub_total = (parseFloat(total)+parseFloat(shipping)).toFixed(2);

    var grand_total = (parseFloat(sub_total)+parseFloat(vat_value)).toFixed(2);

    $('.grandTotal').val(grand_total);
    $('.modalTotal').val(grand_total);
}
```

But this code is only executed when I change some value and NOT on `document.ready();`

Can someone explain why? and how can be function `update_amounts();` can be started on load?

Comment: Seems correct. Is there any error or something?

Comment: the code as shown should run update_amounts on document ready ... do you get any console errors?

Comment: No... there are no errors in console, that' why I can't find a solution.

Comment: if you put a console.log as the first statement inside update_amounts, does it (the console.log) get executed?

Comment: Put a `debugger` inside `update_amounts` and check what values are you getting for `sum`. Is it even looping for table rows?

Comment: It is working fine for me

Comment: values are correctly returned, the form work as expected and all the values are calculate, this code work if I change some val (e.g.: the qty) but not be executed on document.load

Comment: @GirdhariAgrawal it's working on load?

Comment: Is the `#myTable` or contents generated by another function on or after load?

Comment: @eisbehr table content will be generated via a php foreach loop that take values from $_SESSION

Comment: Yes it's working for me check this fiddle with dev console open https://jsfiddle.net/gmL135fe/

Comment: @GirdhariAgrawal I got an error related to subdomain domain or port mismatch only

Comment: @andreaem GirdhariAgrawal's fiddle works for me

Comment: Ok, but isn't what I need, the script is working (as the question message), the only thing isn't working is the calling of the function on page load

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue using

```
$(window).load(function() { update_amounts(); });
```

This will call the function `update_amounts();` when the windows is loaded.